# Storing image logo in local storage while page gets load - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I store image logo in local storage while page gets loaded in angularJS.

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngStorage'
  ]).

  controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage
  ){
    // here I need to store image
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  controller('Ctrl', ['$localStorageProvider', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorageProvider
  ){
    $http.get("http://someurl.com/someimagepath")
         .then(function(response){          
          $scope.myImage = response.data;
          $scope.myImage = window.btoa($scope.myImage); // store it as base64 format
          $localStorageProvider.set('MyImage', $scope.myImage);
         });
    });
  });
```

Use it like

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{myImage}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't save directly image to local storage. We need covert it to base64 then save to local storage

This is demo: How to save convert image to base 64 then save it to local storage
http://jsfiddle.net/8V9w6/

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
            
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
          localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


  if(localStorage.img) { 

         var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML += ['<img class="thumb" src="', localStorage.img,
                            '" title="test"/>'].join('');

          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    
    }
```

```css
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to base64 and store it in localstorage

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" />
```

Create an element in your html file

```
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("preview");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    $localStorage.logo = c.toDataURL()
    alert(c.toDataURL());
```